# How do I update a nested json object in mysql relative to a value

Tags: mysql, json

How do I update a nested json object in mysql relative to a value.

If I have this input and I want that output.

#### Input

```
[{
    "name": "logo",
    "settings": []
}, {
    "name": "other",
    "settings": []
}]
```

#### Output

```
[{
    "name": "logo",
    "settings": [{
        "name": "purpose",
        "value": "logo"
    }]
}, {
    "name": "other",
    "settings": []
}]
```

I've been able to do it If I know the index (0) of the object I want to update. But that index could change.

```
select JSON_EXTRACT('[{"name": "logo","settings": []},{"name": "other","settings": []}]',
    '$[*].name');

select JSON_INSERT('[{"name": "logo","settings": []},{"name": "other","settings": []}]',
    '$[0].settings[1]',
    JSON_OBJECT("name", "purpose", "value", "logo"));
```

Thanks

Comment: The potential problem I see here is that your JSON array data is in one column, in one single row.  I don't know if MySQL supports complex updates of in place JSON this way.  To normalize your data, you could expand that array over multiple records such that each record has one JSON object.

Comment: How do you determine the index to update?.